# Docker MariaDB- I can not conenct to my DB trough mysqlWorkBanch or DBeaver

Tags: linux, database, docker, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm new with docker, linux, and conencting in a remote DB. I'm getting connection failed when I try to connect in my db

I ran these commands:

```
root@jamelaumn:~# ufw status
Status: inactive

sudo docker run -d --name bdmariadb1 -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='!SomePasswordWithExclamation' mariadb
sudo docker start bdmariadb1
```

So. My firewall is deactivated, my container is up, But I cant connect to my Database, why?
I made sure that my VPS Ip is correct, 191.101.234.208, my port is also correct, and also the password, plus the firewall is deactivated

I don't know if it's important but the only db I have installed is inside of my container docker which is MariaDB

Generally when I try to connect, or I get the error failed to coonect, or I receive nothing
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)